# serverspec if condition error

Tags: puppet, serverspec

I have below code in puppet

```
if $::operatingsystemmajrelease < 7 {

     file { '/etc/sudoers' :
      ensure  => present,
      owner   => 'root',
      group   => 'root',
      mode    => '0440',
      content => template('sudo/sudoers.erb'),
    }
  }
```

I wrote serverspec for this

```
require 'spec_helper'

if os[:release] == '6'

  describe file('/etc/sudoers') do
    it { should exist }
    it { should be_owned_by 'root' }
    it { should be_grouped_into 'root' }
    it { should be_mode 440 }
    its(:content) { should match /Defaults    requiretty/}
  end
end
```

1) why I am getting below message

```
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00038 seconds (files took 0.44176 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures
```

My os version is 6 so it should compile my serverspec code but why its failing to execute all the examples.

The serverspec is working if I change it to `if os[:release] < '7'`

2) Also `it { should be_mode 440 }` doesn't support if I give `it { should be_mode 0440` } 4 number octet matching.

getting below error

```
File "/etc/sudoers" should be mode 288
     On host `localhost'
     Failure/Error: it { should be_mode 0440 }
       expected `File "/etc/sudoers".mode?(288)` to return true, got false
       /bin/sh -c stat\ -c\ \%a\ /etc/sudoers\ \|\ grep\ --\ \\\^288\\\$

     # ./spec/localhost/sudo_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.05873 seconds (files took 0.48314 seconds to load)
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Normally `os[:release]` contains values like `'6.5'`. So the correct way to do the comparison would be for example:

```ruby
if os[:release].to_i == 6
```

Or:

```ruby
if os[:release].split('.')[0] == '6'
```

2) Because the numbers with leading zeros are converted from octal (`0440`) to decimal (`288`) by Ruby, and Serverspec (Specinfra) passes it in *decimal-to-string* format to [the underlying *grep* command](https://github.com/mizzy/specinfra/blob/v2.47.1/lib/specinfra/command/base/file.rb#L53-L56).